# Convolution of two rectangular pulses Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing, convolution

I am attempting to find the convolution of two rectangular pulses.

No errors are being thrown - and I am getting a suitably shaped waveform output - however, the magnitude of my answer appears to be vastly too large, and I'm also unsure of how to fit a correct x/time axis to this convolution.

Additionally, the magnitude of the convolution seems to depend on the number of samples in the two pulses (essentially the sampling frequency) - which I would say is incorrect.

As I am attempting to model a continuous time signal, rather than discrete, I have set the sampling frequency very high.

Clearly I am doing something wrong - but what is it, and how do I correct it? 
Thanks very much - and apologies if some of the code is not very "pythonic" (Recent Java convert)!

EDIT: Whilst attempting to evaluate this by hand, I have found that the time axis is too small by a factor of 2; again, I don't know why this would be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.functions.special import delta_functions as dlta

def stepFunction(t): #create pulses below from step-functions
    retval = 0
    if t == 0:
        retval = 1
    else:
        retval = dlta.Heaviside(t)
    return retval

def hT (t=0, start=0, dur=8, samples=1000):

    time = np.linspace(start, start + dur, samples, True)
    data = np.zeros(len(time))
    hTArray = np.column_stack((time, data))

    for row in range(len(hTArray)):
        hTArray[row][1] = 2 * (stepFunction(hTArray[row][0] - 4) - stepFunction(hTArray[row][0] - 6))
    return hTArray

def xT (t=0, start=0, dur=8, samples=1000):

    time = np.linspace(start, start + dur, samples, True)
    data = np.zeros(len(time))
    hTArray = np.column_stack((time, data))

    for row in range(len(hTArray)):
        hTArray[row][1] = (stepFunction(hTArray[row][0]) - stepFunction(hTArray[row][0] - 4))
    return hTArray    


hTArray = hT() #populate two arrays with functions
xTArray = xT()

resCon = np.convolve(hTArray[:, 1], xTArray[:, 1]) #convolute signals/array data


Xaxis = np.linspace(hTArray[0][0], hTArray[len(hTArray) - 1][0],
     len(resCon), endpoint=True)  # create time axis, with same intervals as original functions
#Plot the functions & convolution    
plt.plot(hTArray[:, 0], hTArray[:, 1], label=r'$x1(t)$')
plt.plot(xTArray[:, 0], xTArray[:, 1], label=r'$x2(t)$')
plt.plot(Xaxis, resCon)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
   ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convolute discrete signals, you need to scale appropriately to keep the signal's energy (integral over |x(t)|²) constant:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 8, n)
T = t[1] - t[0]  # sampling width

x1 = np.where(t<=4, 1, 0) # build input functions
x2 = np.where(np.logical_and(t>=4, t<=6), 2, 0)

y = np.convolve(x1, x2, mode='full') * T  # scaled convolution 
ty = np.linspace(0, 2*8, n*2-1)  # double time interval

# plot results:    
fg, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(t, x1, label="$x_1$")
ax.plot(t, x2, label="$x_2$")
ax.plot(ty, y, label="$x_1\\star x_2$")
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.grid(True)

fg.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Sorry - just to add a follow up question - why is the time interval doubled, and why is multiplying by the time interval equivalent to |x(t)²|? Thanks!

Comment: The doubled length of the output array has to do with the way ``np.convolve()`` is implemented, namely with ``mode=full`` - read the documentation on that. Another way of explaining the scaling: An discretized integral (here the convolution or for the enegy) over *z(t)* becomes the *sum_k z(t_k)*T*. ``np.convolve()`` assumes ``T=1``, hence the multiplication with ``T``.